# Returing values from controller to js after remote call

Tags: jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I know this is kind of basic but i am having problem sending data from controller to .js.erb page in my rails application

I am able to call my main controller using remote=>true from my link_to function.
This code is in my index.html.erb page

```
<%= link_to 'Process', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' },:remote=>true,:class=>"test" %>
```

In my contrller i do something and want to return some data to default ajax return page which will be index.js.erb

```
def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.destroy
  @test = 1
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
    format.json {render json: @test}
    format.js  #this will redirect me to index.js.erb page where i would like to manipulate @test 
  end
end
```

This i trivial but can you tell how we can set pass @test to index.js.erb so that i can use it as data and also retrieve it

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use instance variables in js templates the same as html templates. The only thing to note is, you need to wrap the server output in `javascript_escape`.

```
# index.js.erb
$('#some-div').html('<%= j(@test) %>)
```

`j` is alias for `javascript_escape`

Comment: ok i got it.Thanks... How about json. how can we retrieve it in .js.erb file??